# How to store multiple lat long in arrays and access them in waypoints to create route between them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, google-maps, maps

I have added on click add marker function to my java script part in google map api. I want to click multiple markers and create a route between them. I am able to place marker and next part is to store the lat long in array and access the value in way points so that the way points are accessed from the marker's lat long. I don't want to give the lat long manually every time. That is why creating this one. Suggestions please.

```js
function mapLocation() {

    var values = [];

    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;


    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(37.334818, -121.884886);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: chicago
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('routebtn'), 'click', calcRoute);


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        alert(e.latLng.lat() + ", " + e.latLng.lng());
        placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
        values = {lat:e.latLng.lat(),lng:e.latLng.lng()};
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lon = position.coords.longitude;
                values.push(lat, lon);
        });

        });
    }

    function placeMarker(position, map) {


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
        });  
        map.panTo(position);
    }


    function calcRoute() {
        var a = new google.maps.LatLng(values.lat, values.lng);
        //var end = new google.maps.LatLng(38.334818, -181.884886);
        var b = new google.maps.LatLng(values.lat, values.lng);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds.extend(a);
        bounds.extend(b);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        var request = {
            origin: a,
            destination: b,
            waypoints: [{location: a, stopover: false},
                        {location: b, stopover: false}],

            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            } else {
                alert("Directions Request from " + a.toUrlValue(6) + " to " + b.toUrlValue(6) + " failed: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
mapLocation();
```

Comment: I Just Solved it!!!

Comment: Can you please answer your own question and accept it for the community's sake? Thx.

Comment: Check my answer for using waypoints as a marker and plotting route between them. max waypoints can be clicked 25.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution with us! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Routing</title>
    <style>
        html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
    </style>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&callback=mapLocation"></script>
    <script>
    function mapLocation() {

    var values = [];


    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;


    function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(37.54866603021222, -77.44119330331694);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: chicago
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('routebtn'), 'click', calcRoute);


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
        alert(e.latLng.lat() + ", " + e.latLng.lng());
        placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
        console.log(e.latLng)
        values.push({lat:e.latLng.lat(),lng:e.latLng.lng()});
        console.log("values",values);
       /* navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lon = position.coords.longitude;
                values.push(lat, lon);
        });*/

        });
    }

    function placeMarker(position, map) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
        });  


        map.panTo(position);
    }



    function calcRoute() {
        console.log(values);
        var waypoints_data = [];
        var i;


        for(i = 1; i < values.length-1; i++){
            var loc = new google.maps.LatLng(values[i]);
            waypoints_data.push({location:loc,stopover: false}); 
        }


        /*var a = new google.maps.LatLng(values.lat, values.lng);
        //var end = new google.maps.LatLng(38.334818, -181.884886);
        var b = new google.maps.LatLng(values.lat, values.lng);
        /*var c = new google.maps.LatLng(51.50748705717662, -0.13893842697143555);
        var d = new google.maps.LatLng(51.50346856667175, -0.14929282090679408);
        var e = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51083871071007, -0.1570619682540837);
        var f = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51334975342731, -0.15831470489501953);
        var g = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514163869310785, -0.1615037063827458);
        var h = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51796947585254, -0.1516760925521794);
        var i = new google.maps.LatLng(51.519611797295354, -0.1447636425947394);
        var j = new google.maps.LatLng(51.51742202221118, -0.14268224839918275);
        var k = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5138700899723, -0.14141624574415346);
        var l = new google.maps.LatLng(51.50902430327333, -0.12421940501076278);
        /*
var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: start,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
        var endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: end,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });
*/
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds.extend(values[0]);
        bounds.extend(values[values.length-1]);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        var request = {
            origin: values[0],
            destination: values[values.length-1],
            waypoints: waypoints_data,

                        //[{location: a, stopover: false},
                        //{location: b, stopover: false}],
                        /*{location: c, stopover: false},
                        {location: d, stopover: false},
                        {location: e, stopover: false},
                        {location: f, stopover: false},
                        {location: g, stopover: false},
                        {location: h, stopover: false},
                        {location: i, stopover: false},
                        {location: j, stopover: false},
                        {location: k, stopover: false},
                        {location: l, stopover: false}],*/
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            } else {
                alert("Directions Request from " + values[0].toUrlValue(6) + " to " + values[values.length-1].toUrlValue(6) + " failed: " + status);
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
mapLocation();
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" id="routebtn" value="route" />
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place your api key in script part.

Comment: on click at every location you ll get a marker with latlong popup and max way points can be 25 set by google. click on route to plot route between them.